# Using a button to destroy another one using Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a tic tack toe game, but I can't seem to figure out how to delete a button, with another one. I've tried inputing the function into the pack_forget, and grid_forget, but both give me errors. The code is below

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()
turtle.screen = Screen()
i = 360
up = Turtle()
up.forward(180)
up.back(360)
up.forward(360/3)
up.right(90)
up.forward(180)
up.back(275)
up.forward(95)
up.left(90)
up.forward(360/3)
up.right(90)
up.forward(180)
up.back(275)
up.forward(275-180+90)
up.right(90)
up.forward(360/3*2)
up.back(360)

def TopLeftO(event):
    topleft = True
    i = 360


    up.seth(180)
    up.up()
    up.goto(-100,20)
    while i > 0:
        up.down()
        up.speed(0)
        up.forward(0.5)
        up.right(1)
        i-=1
    i=360
    event.widget.pack_forget()
    #insert function to delete 2nd button
def TopLeftX(event):
    topleft = True




    up.up()
    up.goto(-100,20)
    up.seth(0)
    up.down()
    up.left(45)
    up.forward(30+20)
    up.back(15+10)
    up.right(90)
    up.forward(15+20)
    up.back(30+40)
    event.widget.pack_forget()
    #insert code to delete first button



toplefto = Button(root, text = "top left for player O");
toplefto.bind('<Button-1>', TopLeftO)
toplefto.pack()
topleftx = Button(root, text = "top left for player X")
topleftx.bind('<Button-1>', TopLeftX)
topleftx.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function TopLeftX and button topleftx have similar names. Calling `topleftx.pack_forget()` removes the button, calling `TopLeftX.pack_forget()` throws an error. Renaming your variables and functions to different names would help clear up confusion.

It would also probably help to look into 2 dimensional lists in python for storing the buttons.

I moved the button removal to near the beginning of the callbacks so a person can't click the other one.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *

root =Tk()
turtle.screen = Screen()
i = 360
up = Turtle()
up.forward(180)
up.back(360)
up.forward(360/3)
up.right(90)
up.forward(180)
up.back(275)
up.forward(95)
up.left(90)
up.forward(360/3)
up.right(90)
up.forward(180)
up.back(275)
up.forward(275-180+90)
up.right(90)
up.forward(360/3*2)
up.back(360)


toplefto = Button(root, text = "top left for player O")
topleftx = Button(root, text = "top left for player X")

def TopLeftO(event):
    topleft = True
    i = 360

    event.widget.pack_forget()
    #insert function to delete 2nd button
    topleftx.pack_forget()

    up.seth(180)
    up.up()
    up.goto(-100,20)
    while i > 0:
        up.down()
        up.speed(0)
        up.forward(0.5)
        up.right(1)
        i-=1
    i=360

def TopLeftX(event):
    topleft = True

    event.widget.pack_forget()
    #insert code to delete first button
    toplefto.pack_forget()

    up.up()
    up.goto(-100,20)
    up.seth(0)
    up.down()
    up.left(45)
    up.forward(30+20)
    up.back(15+10)
    up.right(90)
    up.forward(15+20)
    up.back(30+40)


toplefto.bind('<Button-1>', TopLeftO)
toplefto.pack()

topleftx.bind('<Button-1>', TopLeftX)
topleftx.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think to use common sense and put the button name beforehand. Thanks